# not able to autowire bean from spring parent(shared) context

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, websphere

I have simple .war with 2 spring contexts.
My web.xml contains:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>parentContextKey</param-name>
    <param-value>ejbContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

beanRefContext.xml:

```
<bean id="ejbContext" class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
    <property name="configLocation" value="WEB-INF/eeContext.xml"></property>
</bean>
```

eeContext.xml

```
    <bean name="parentSpringBean" class="ru.fns.bean.spring.ParentSpringBean">
        <property name="stringProperty" value="parentSpringBean.stringProperty value"></property>
    </bean>
```

As it represented above parent context has only one bean definition, according on docs it means that it must be accessible among EJB and children spring contexts. Indeed, ejb bean works just fine with injected parentSpringBean, but autowiring this bean into the bean, that defined in child context - it fails with message:

> 000002b3 ContextLoader E org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
>                                    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springBean': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ru.fns.bean.spring.ParentSpringBean ru.fns.bean.spring.SpringBean.parentSpringBean; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [ru.fns.bean.spring.ParentSpringBean] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

applicationContext.xml contains:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.fns"/>
```

springBean code:

```
@Component()
@Qualifier("springBean")
public class SpringBean {
private static transient final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringBean.class);

@Value("${logs.level}")
private String stringProperty;

@EJB(mappedName = "EEBean")
private EEBean eeBean;


@Autowired
@Qualifier("parentSpringBean")
private ParentSpringBean parentSpringBean; // it fails
```

Moreover, injecting springBean into parentSpringBean works ok, but how?!

parentSpringBean code sample:

```
 // there's neither @Component nor @Service annotation
public class ParentSpringBean {
private static transient final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ParentSpringBean.class);

private String stringProperty;

@EJB(mappedName = "EEBean")
private EEBean eeBean; // ok



@Autowired
private SpringBean springBean; // child context bean, works but why?
```

I've been testing it on WebSphere for a couple of days and still i can't understand such strange behavior. Does anybody know the reason why this is happening so? Thanks beforehand.